# I am trying to create a virtual environment but the "done" never appears

Tags: python, cmd

I have tried to create a `virtualenv`, but I could never create it because it always stays installing the wheels and never stops blinking.
I have also tried to verify whether the virtual environment exists through `lsvirtualenv` but it does not identify the command even with the `virtualenvwrapper` installed.

[image: after wheel it never finishes installing and sending the "done"]

Answer (score 0):

What exact code did you use? You could try this:

`conda create -n myenv anaconda python=x.x` (x.x is the python version you want)

I think the installation of some modules may need internet conection, maybe you had conection problems?

In [this link](http://know.continuum.io/rs/387-XNW-688/images/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) you can find a very usefull cheat sheet for managing you conda envs.

I'm asuming you use anaconda!